# Return object with interface function type using typecript node js express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

I have a question, I want to use typescript in an api rest, node and express, I want to return a function with a type.

```
export interface IPost extends Document {
title: string,
url: string,
content: string,
image: string,
createAt: Date,
updateAt: Date}
```

Also mongoose for queries to the bd.
in the following way I have no syntax error, the interface matches the query, but does not return anything to the client.
I am using postman as a client, but the request never returns

```
 async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<IPost[]>{
    const posts = await PostModel.find();
    return posts;
}
```

and as follows if you return the json to the client but it does not match

```
  async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<IPost[]>{
    const posts = await PostModel.find();
    res.json(posts);
}
```

the following error appears
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.ts(2355).

Comment: `index` doesnt return anything

Comment: How should it be for me to return something?

Comment: Actually it should return `void` (that is nothing). The scope ofTypeScript is the language itself. `index` sends the response to the client as a side-effect. But the function itself doesnt return anything in the scope of the javascript language.